# fopen permission denied apache server

Tags: php, apache, fopen

code(located in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php):

```
<?php

$logging = <<< LOG
This is a test
LOG;

$testfile = fopen('/home/djameson/test.txt','a');  // append  mode
fwrite ($testfile, $logging);
fclose($testfile);

?>
```

test.txt(in /home/djameson/test.txt):

```
-rwxrw-r--.  1 apache   apache       0 Feb 28 20:21 test.txt
```

Errors:

```
Warning: fopen(/home/djameson/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 7

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 8

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/fileio_test/io_test.php on line 9
```

Been at this for a number of days changing around file permissions, adding test.txt to different groups but I have not been able to write to a file. Any ideas?

The results of sestatus:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Additional Information:

The server runs on fedora 20;
apache server located /var/www

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Probably selinux is enforcing its rules. 
From [Selinux's wiki on fedoraproject](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache)

> httpd by default is not allowed to access users home  directories.
>   If you  want to allow access to users home directories you need to set
>   the httpd_enable_homedirs boolean and change the context of the files 
>   that you want people to access off the home dir.

You should therefore try disabling temporarily selinux -> `setenforce 0` (**WARN**: This will disable entirely selinux on your system for the current session DO NOT RUN this on a production server). If after this it works probably is the sebool `httpd_enable_homedirs` that is being enforced. Should you wish to disable just that flag instead of entirely disabling selinux you can run:

```
setsebool httpd_enable_homedirs 1 //This will enable for the current session only
```

if you want to set it permanently:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1 //Permanent
```

After setting this you should run a chcon or restorecon on the user home dir:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/djameson
```

Comment: Ran the commands setenforce 0, no effect. I then ran setsebool httpd_enable_homedirs 1 and chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/djameson. None of these commands had any effect unfortunately. I restarted with sudo service httpd restart just to be sure.

Comment: can you post the results of getsebool -a | grep httpd ?

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Antonio's post is what I had in mind. One thing you might check though is that `apache` can actually access `/home/djameson` (chmod +x is your friend).